Replacing D3S Xenon head light bulb myself
Hi one of my low beam head lights is not working, got a quote from my dealer, came back at around $360 for a single bulb and $550 in total including labour. Think that is a total rip off. So I am thinking to replace it myself.
I have taken out the non-working bulb already and it looks exactly like this:

I found new one on Amazon just around $100, its nowhere near that $360 quote from dealer. Its just the model number doesn't match exactly (mine said D3S 9285335244, the one on Amazon said D3S 9285304244), I don't know if that is still OK?
Then I also found an even cheaper one like this:

I wonder if my non-working light bulb can be taken out from the square base and be replaced with this (reusing the base)?
And lastly, is it possible to replace with D3S LED instead for its longer life span? Would I need specific model number or any D3S LED would match?
Thank you!

Search around for competitive pricing for direct replacement of oem D3S hid lamps. No one is obligated to buy from new car dealers; all their parts are marked up to pay for overhead costs of a dealership. You can buy the exact same D3S lamps anywhere. If I'm not mistaken, the base is the ballast, needed to boost 12v to whatever higher voltage is needed to startup (high initial current) then maintain voltage and current to operate HID lamps efficiently. It may not be wise to reuse the base with a replacement lamp. The quartz glass is sensitive to human body oils from mishandling, shattering once they reach operating temperatures. However, if you choose led replacements, you might see a different beam pattern not matching the other side (HID). Research carefully on whether to switch to leds (possibly both sides) or remain with stock HID lighting. Search for information on troubleshooting HID lamp failure.
